# Python Selenium Firefox driver. Message: TypeError: rect is undefined

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

My program works in the Chrome driver but has memory crashing issues so I am trying in Firefox which I read would maybe solve this issue. I thought firefox might be the issue but I can reproduce this in the repl and have it work. I have read multiple threads, seems to be a few issues that can produce this 1. Element is not in Viewport 2. Element has not been loaded.

This code is for inserting a password into a google-sign-in for a work website.

```py
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'google-sign-in-title').click()
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierId').send_keys('USERNAME')
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#identifierNext > div > button > span").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
 
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='password']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

also tried the scrollintoview method with executable_scripts:

```py
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
element.click()
```

This fails silently.

As a side note the point is not to click this element, it's to send_keys to the element to enter my password. if I try:

```py
element.send_keys(password())
```

I get an error Message: Element  is not reachable by keyboard

```py
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='password']")   print(len(elements))   
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']")   print(len(elements))   
try:     
   element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='password']").click()   
except:     
   element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='password']").click()
```

### Output:

1 
  1 
  selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view 
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 
  selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view

```py
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']")))
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

same error -> essage: TypeError: rect is undefined

Comment: I'm pretty surprised this works in Chrome... google used to prevent bots from signing in.  The rect undefined error sounds like it would come from client side... when trying to scroll.  Does that error appear without the scroll?  (The scroll is not necessary, btw... Selenium will automatically scroll the element into view.)

Comment: "Message: Element <input class="F29zPe" name="hiddenPassword" type="password"> could not be scrolled into view." when I try that. 
I'll try with XPATH. 
Got: " Message: Element <input class="whsOnd zHQkBf" name="password" type="password"> could not be scrolled into view"

Comment: don't target by the type attribute... looks like there's 2 of those and one is hidden... target the 'name' attribute instead, so you get the correct one.  Maybe also ditch the implicitwaits and use explicit visibilityOfElementLocated(By...)  It's possible that it's there but not yet visible... which would explain why you're getting the "rect" error.  (the bounding rectangle would have zero size...)